# MLE by rounding xbar to nearest integer

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

Suppose $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ - 
$iid ∼ \mathcal{N}(µ, σ2)$, where $µ ∈ Z$ and $σ$ is a power of 10, i.e. $log_{10}(σ) ∈ Z$.

a) Show that $f(a)
=\sum((x_i − \bar{x} - a)^2)$
is a symmetric function with respect to $a$. That is, prove
that $f(a) = f(−a)$.

b) Use your answer in (a) to argue that the MLE can be found by rounding $\bar{x}$ to the nearest integer.

c) Propose an estimator for $σ$ that maximizes the likelihood such that $log_{10}(σ) ∈ Z$.

I solved a, but I'm not quite sure for b and c. Please.

Comment: Sketch the graph of the likelihood (as a function of $\mu$ in (b) and as a function of $\sigma$ in (c)).